# Difference between using for and if for searching for element in python

Tags: python, arrays

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

if 6 in a:
        print("yes")
```

I just want to know the difference between these two as these will give the same answer.

```
for x in a:

    if x==6:
        print("yes")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are multiple instances of `6` in the array, the second will print `"yes"` multiple times, although I believe there's a method for counting instances of an object that is more efficient than that.

The first method also uses the `in` keyword to find out if `a` contains `6`, which is generally the best way to find out this sort of thing in Python.

Comment: So, using 'in' is better than using 'for' for just finding an element in the 'list' or an 'array'??

Comment: Yes, most of the time it's much more clear